# Why is the PPO agent in RL giving negative rewards after each iteration during the training process and what are the possible hyperparameter values?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I am using the mujoco simulator as my training environment. I loaded Ant-v3 for the agent to train on. It is persistently producing negative rewards after each iteration performed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Basically, when I'm training the agent, the mean average rewards after every iteration turn out to be negative, is it normal as I'm new to RL?